# kotlin sourcesJar to debug library

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, kotlin

I am trying to build and publish a sourcesJar to artifactory for a kotlin library.

I can see the sources on artifactory, but intelliJ is not happy with the downloaded sources

> "IDEA cannot determine what kind of files the chosen items contain.do
>   you want to attach them as sources?"

This is my gradle sources task:

```
task sourceJar(type: Jar) {
    classifier = 'sources'
    from sourceSets.main.allJava
}

publishing {
//    Enable publishing of artifacts
    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
            from components.java
            artifact tasks.sourceJar
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When do you get this? What is the jar file name? Check that it actually contains the source files.

Comment: I fixed it... I changed from sourceSets.main.allJava to allSources

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If found the problem. To include kotlin sources, I had to use the allSource sourceset instead of allJava

```
task sourceJar(type: Jar) {
    classifier = 'sources'
    from sourceSets.main.allSource
}
```